# How to reference a cell in a excel hyperlink

Tags: excel, hyperlink, excel-formula

This is what I have tried

```
    =HYPERLINK("#"+M4+"!A1","Go To Go To Store")
```

The first section does not add the cell value to the other parts of the string.

It outputs "#"+"Text"+"!A1" instead of #Text!A1

If I am far off the overall objective is to get a list of hyperlinks to every spreadsheet into a drop down list please can you advise on that

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need using text concatenation. But `+` is only add up operator in Excel. Text concatenation is `&`.

So

```
=HYPERLINK("#"&M4&"!A1","Go To Go To Store")
```

But if the single sheet names in `M4` can be multiple words delimited with spaces, then they must be enclosed within single quotes. So

```
=HYPERLINK("#'"&M4&"'!A1","Go To Go To Store")
```

will be more flexible.